# Excel Upload in S3 is failling using Java code

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload a dynamic Excel file in S3 Bucket without storing it in local system.

I have written a code to do so but it is giving error. Please help

```
public static void uploadToCloud(HSSFWorkbook excelWorkBook) throws IOException
{
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("a-b-c", "d-e-f");
    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

    for (Bucket bucket : s3client.listBuckets()) {
        System.out.println("Bucket Name - " + bucket.getName());
        String bucketnameS3 = bucket.getName();
        System.out.println("Bucket Creation date - "+bucket.getCreationDate());       

        //creating local file just for testing. This part of code is working as expected.
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));
            excelWorkBook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.flush();
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //upload to amazon s3
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            excelWorkBook.write(byteArrayOutputStream);
            byteArrayOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        ByteArrayInputStream bi= new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());

        bi.read(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());

        Long contentLength = Long.valueOf(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray().length);

        ObjectMetadata objectMetaData =new ObjectMetadata();
        objectMetaData.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        objectMetaData.setContentLength(contentLength);

        s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketnameS3,"test.xls",bi,objectMetaData) );

        bi.close();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
[12/14/18 13:08:14:436 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Data read has a different length than the expected: 
 dataLength=0;
 expectedLength=165376;
 includeSkipped=false;
 in.getClass()=class com.amazonaws.internal.ReleasableInputStream;
 markedSupported=true;
 marked=0;
 resetSinceLastMarked=false; 
 markCount=1; 
 resetCount=0
[12/14/18 13:08:14:437 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at com.amazonaws.util.LengthCheckInputStream.checkLength(LengthCheckInputStream.java:151)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:437 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at com.amazonaws.util.LengthCheckInputStream.read(LengthCheckInputStream.java:109)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:437 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:437 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.MD5DigestCalculatingInputStream.read(MD5DigestCalculatingInputStream.java:128)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:437 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:437 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:180)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:437 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:438 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity.writeTo(InputStreamEntity.java:142)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:438 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at com.amazonaws.http.RepeatableInputStreamRequestEntity.writeTo(RepeatableInputStreamRequestEntity.java:160)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:438 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:158)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:438 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:162)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:438 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:237)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:439 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:63)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:439 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:122)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:439 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:439 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:439 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:439 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:439 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:439 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:440 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1285)
[12/14/18 13:08:14:440 IST] 000000ee SystemErr     R  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1101)
```

I am using `aws-java-sdk-1.11.464.jar`.

Answer (score 3):

The issue has been resolved and my code is working fine now.

bi.read(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());---- This line needs to be removed from the code.